# How to stop loading when web page is loading by use jquery?

Tags: jquery, submit, loading

Here is my use-case - I want in my web page, after user clicks a submit button to load a webpage, It will show a message box ( with a stop-loading button). I want after user click "stop loading " button, the new web page will have stopped loading.

Comment: What do you mean? Improve your question with relevant code, maybe...

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for a

```
window.stop();
```

function? It is javaScript function and im not sure if IE supports it.